# The number of times a stock hits a support / resistence area vs the chances of it breaking out

Tags: stock-analysis, stock-valuation

I've seen two contradicting claims from reputable authors:

A: The more times a stock hits a support or resistance area the **weaker** it becomes (and the possibility of a breakout *increases*).

B: The more times a stock hits a support or resistance area the **stronger** becomes (and the possibility of a breakout *decreases*).

Which one is true? When a stock bounces between a resistance and support zone, does the chance of breaking the support / resistance increase or decrease with the increased number of touches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support is the level at which demand is strong enough to  prevent further share price decrease.

Resistance is the level at which supply is strong enough to prevent further share price increase.

All other things being equal, the psychology of support and resistance (for buyers) is that if they bought at support and sold at resistance, they'll be happy to buy again if support is reached again.  In addition, those that wanted to buy at support but missed the opportunity will also be willing to buy at $50.

It stands to reason that the more times the stock hits a support or resistance area, the greater the number of the aforementioned willing buyers and the higher the likelihood that support and resistance will be  not breached. However, this is not quantifiable since this is sentiment.

Note that support and resistance levels suggested by trendlines is very subjective.  AFAIC, a more reliable indicator is a Point & Figure chart which is not subjective and removes the noise.  You can vary the box size to see short, intermediate and long term support and resistance:

[image]